# weblogic-maven-plugin WS clientgen creates SequenceCodec instead of class

Tags: maven, plugins, weblogic, codec

I am coverting an ant project to Maven. Using the class
weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.ClientGenTask
Ant was generating the classes from the WSDL. Example:
com.company.ArrayOfQualifyingActivity

But now using Maven plugin, it's creating
com.company.ArrayOfQualifyingActivitySequenceCodec

Has anyone else run into this before?

Edit:
Never mind. Resolved the issue. The previous clientgen was wrapping arrays of classes (for QualifyingActivity[] ) in a wrapper class.
The maven clientgen is not doing that. So I can use the QualifyingArray[] or String[] etc... as is.

Thanks